# how can i make the object move on that path in unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want my enemy to be move like this in this picture. How can i achieve this in unity 2d.
[image: This is the directional path]

Comment: well A) define the path, B) make the object move on that path, C) repeat .. what exactly are you asking about ? / Which of these points do not work for you as expected?

Comment: all three points.

Comment: Please make sure to go through the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous ways to achieve that. A good starting point is a state machine.

- You have a state which decides in which direction you are currently moving.
- After a certain time (or condition is met) you change the state.

sample code:

```
{
    private int state = 1; // 1 means moving down and right, 2 means moving up.
                           // you could also use an enum for this.
    private float time = 0; // how long the enemy is already moving in this direction

    void Update() {
        if (state == 1) {
            // move down right
            transform.position = transform.position + new Vector(1,-1,0) * Time.deltaTime;
        } else if (state == 2) {
            // move up
            // TODO
        }
        // Add additional states here...

        time += Time.deltaTime; // track how long you are in this state
        
        // Change the condition here...
        if (time > TIME_MOVING_IN_SAME_DIRECTION) {
            time = 0; // reset time
            
            // set next state:
            if (state == 1) state = 2;
            else if (state == 2) state = 1;
            // Add additional changes between the states here if necessary
        }
    }
}
```